# Importing specific XML file to mySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, import

I have a specific XML-file that I would like to import into a mySQL table. The XML-file generally follows this structure:

```
<Competitor>
    <Person sex="M">
        <PersonName>
            <Family>LastName</Family>
            <Given sequence="1">GivenName</Given>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonId idManager="SWE" type="nat">2654</PersonId>
        <BirthDate>
            <Date dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD">1990-01-01</Date>
        </BirthDate>
        <Nationality>
            <CountryId value="NOR"/>
        </Nationality>
        <ModifyDate>
            <Date dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD">2011-05-07</Date>
            <Clock clockFormat="HH:MM:SS">11:55:05</Clock>
        </ModifyDate>
    </Person>
    <ClubId>184</ClubId>
    <ModifyDate>
        <Date dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD">2011-05-07</Date>
        <Clock clockFormat="HH:MM:SS">11:55:05</Clock>
    </ModifyDate>
</Competitor>
```

Some competitor entries have some additional lines as well.

I would like to put the name, birth date, PersonId and ClubId in a mySQL table. The table I have used this far looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `rekr` (
  `PersonId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Family` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Given` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClubId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have tried the default import command from the mySQL documentation `load xml local infile 'file.xml' into table rekr rows identified by '<Competitor>';`. This creates one entry in the table with PersonId = 0, Family = NULL, Given = Null and ClubId = 403. ClubId 403 is the same as the first entry in the XML file, so some portion of the code works at least. I guess there are some problems with the name in the XML file being "contained" by both PersonName and Family/Given. I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Update:** I ended up tidying up the XML-file with some vim macros, so that the only data between  and  were the data I needed. It then became quite easy to import into mySQL. Problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using a powershell script ... it will create the file query.sql that you can import to mysql :

```
[xml]$xml=gc C:\path\to\xml.xml 

$xml.competitors.competitor | %{ 
    $sql="insert into rerk values ('','"+$_.person.personname.family+"','"+$($_.person.personname.Given.innerText)+"','"+$($_.clubId)+"')"

    $sql |out-file c:\temp\so\query.sql -append
}
```

content of query.sql :

```
insert into rerk values ('','LastName','GivenName','184')
insert into rerk values ('','LastName2','GivenName','184')
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am on a Mac, IIRC Powershell is only available for Windows.